# Angular 6 and Angular Material - mat-radio-group [(ngModel)] set dynamic variable inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 6 and Angular Angular Material, 
I have dynamic list of polls with list of options. I want to show selected option with two way data binding. as my list is dynamic i want to pass variable in [(ngModel)]. tried passing variable but no luck please suggest alternate solution [stackblitz example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-with-dyamic-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using the same variable (`mySelection`) for both questions. Instead, you need to use two different variables, or even better, an array. Here's [the fixed version on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-two-way-data-binding-with-dyamic-name-7uoytr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and here's the relevant code.

## Template

```
<ol>
    <li *ngFor="let poll of polls;let i = index">
        {{poll.name}}

        <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="selectedAnswers[i]">
            <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let option of poll.options" [value]="option.answer">
                {{option.answer}}
            </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
    <strong>Seleted Answer : {{selectedAnswers[i]}}</strong>
    <button  [disabled]="selectedAnswers[i]==undefined" mat-raised-button color="accent">save</button>
  </li>
</ol>

<pre>{{ selectedAnswers | json }}</pre>
```

## Component

```
@Component({
  /* ... */
})
export class AppComponent  {

  selectedAnswers = []

  polls = [
    /* ... */
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lazar , Thats exactly i wanted . Great Help

Comment: Hi Lazer this solution work fine for  local array but in case of  http GET data  of poll s facing issue screenshot attached .

Comment: Where you get the data from has nothing to do with the solution. Please open a new question if you're facing a new type of issue. (By the way, you should mark an answer as accepted by using the green tick below the up/down voting arrows if this answer has solved your problem.)

Comment: Where's the I come from ? Where's You should add the code for the index. SelectedAnswers should be strict typed also.

Comment: Sorry, what...?